# How to send an image from url with ACTION_SEND intent to other app?

Tags: android, android-intent

The image is an url, like http://www.example.com/123/abc.jpg

I want to share some text and an image with other app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String.format(getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.share_text), pid));
intent.setType("image/jpg");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/123/abc.jpg"));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"),
                        Settings.SHARE_REQUEST);
```

But it is not work. It seems like the uri should be a local image? If this is true, how can I convert the image url to a local uri? Thanks!

Comment: You want to share in same device or some remote device over WIFI.

Comment: @BlueGreen Same device, like open in gmail, twitter, or facebook to post.

Answer (score -1):

See [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) for details on sharing.  You should not need to call `startActivityForResult()`.  Just call `startActivity()` and it will properly prompt the user for where to send the data (i.e. pick Gmail, browser, etc.)

Comment: I have tried, but it is not work for the image. So I think it may be cannot pass a image url this way?

Comment: Do you need to share the image and the text, or could you share the text plus a link to the URL?  I suspect the problem is that you are trying to share both text and image stream data at the same time.  Your second call to `setType()` is basically overriding the first.

Comment: Yes, I want to share text and image, the image is from a URL, should show it, not just show a link, can you please tell me what is right way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Something you could try would be to use the SEND_MULTIPLE Intent, if your text to send can be encoded as a URI as well.  Another option you might try just sharing the URL as the EXTRA_TEXT then send your text string as EXTRA_SUBJECT.  Keep the type set to the text MIME type.  It will be up to the receiving app to do the right thing with the data.  Offhand, I'm not aware of a way to embed both stream data and text data in the same Intent.